# Updating highly read Lists/Maps in a concurrent environment

Tags: java, concurrency, assignment-operator

The following class acts as a simple cache that gets updated very infrequently (say e.g. twice a day) and gets read quite a lot (up to several times a second). There are two different types, a `List` and a `Map`. My question is about the new assignment after the data gets updated in the `update` method. What's the best (safest) way for the new data to get applied?

I should add that it isn't necessary for readers to see the absolute latest value. The requirements are just to get either the old or the new value at any given time.

```
public class Foo {

    private ThreadPoolExecutor _executor;
    private List<Object> _listObjects = new ArrayList<Object>(0);
    private Map<Integer, Object> _mapObjects = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
    private Object _mutex = new Object();
    private boolean _updateInProgress;

    public void update() {

        synchronized (_mutex) {
            if (_updateInProgress) {
                return;
            } else {
                _updateInProgress = true;
            }
        }

        _executor.execute(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    List<Object> newObjects = loadListObjectsFromDatabase();
                    Map<Integer, Object> newMapObjects = loadMapObjectsFromDatabase();

                    /*
                     * this is the interesting part
                     */
                    _listObjects = newObjects;
                    _mapObjects = newMapObjects;

                } catch (final Exception ex) {
                    // error handling
                } finally {
                    synchronized (_mutex) {
                        _updateInProgress = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Object getObjectById(Integer id) {
        return _mapObjects.get(id);
    }

    public List<Object> getListObjects() {
        return new ArrayList<Object>(_listObjects);
    }


}
```

As you see, currently no `ConcurrentHashMap` or `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is used. The only synchronisation is done in the update method.

Although not necessary for my current problem, it would be also great to know the best solution for cases where it is essential for readers to always get the absolute latest value.

Comment: One possible issue that comes to mind is that a thread could call any of the get methods between the `_listObjects = newObjects` line and the `_mapObjects = newMapObjects` line. Do the 2 structures need to be consistent (i.e. both are old or both are updated)?

Comment: does loadListObjectsFromDatabase() loads your data from disk?

Comment: assylias, no they don't have to be consistent, Ofek - well, from a database (MySQL in my case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use plan synchronization unless you are reading over 10,000 times per second.

If you want concurrent access I would use on of the concurrent collections like ConcurrentHashMap or CopyOnWriteArrayList. These are simpler to use than synchronizing the collection. (i.e. you don't need them for performance reasons, use them for simplicity)

BTW: A modern CPU can perform billions of operations in 0.1 seconds so several times a second is an eternity to a computer.

Comment: out of interest, why 10,000 times per second? Is that a working limit you've found for apps or a theoretical limit? I'd be interested if you could expand on that. Thanks, as usual you've got interesting answers on SO :)

Comment: Its an order magnitude which I would say I can't imagine you would have a problem. At 100K tasks per second you may have to be more careful how you implement your system and over one million tasks per second you have to design your system around this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I am also seeing this issue and think of multiple solutions:

1. Use synchronization block on the both codes, one where reading and other where writing.
2. Make a separate remove list, add all removable items in that list. Remove in the same thread where reading the list just after reading is done. This way reading and deleting will happen in sequence and no error will come.